# Why isn't the last row of buttons on my calculator not aligned as all the rest of the buttons are?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for hours and to no end to get the last row of red buttons on my calculator to align in the same way that all the other buttons on my calculator are aligned, however it just will not align! I do not know why! Can you show me where in my code I have gone wrong?

Here is the link to my CodePen:
https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/zEBoOQ/

Here is my HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ziontific Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 id="heading">ZIONTIFIC CALCULATOR</h1>
        <div class="form holder">
           <form id="formone" name="calc">
          <input id="display" type="text" name="display" value=".....Get on board...." disabled contenteditable="false" >
          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="1" onClick=”calc.display.value+=1”>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="2" onClick="calc.display.value+=2">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="3" onClick="calc.display.value+=3">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="C" onClick="Resetfunction(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="<-" onClick="backspace(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="=" onClick="evaluation(this.form)">
          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="4" onClick="calc.display.value+=4">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="5" onClick="calc.display.value+=5">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="6" onClick="calc.display.value+=6">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="-" onClick="calc.display.value+='-'">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="%" onClick="calc.display.value+='%'">
          <input class="button end one" type="button" value="cos" onClick="cos_function()">
          <br>


          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="7" onClick=”calc.display.value+=7”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="8" onClick=”calc.display.value+=8”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="9" onClick=”calc.display.value+=9”>
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="*" onClick="calc.display.value+='*'">
          <input class="button n" type="button" value="n!" onClick="fact_function()">
          <input class="button sin"type="button" value="sin" onClick="sin_function()">
          <br>
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="." onClick="calc.display.value+='.'">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="0" onClick="calc.display.value+=0">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="," onClick="calc.display.value+=','">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="+" onClick="calc.display.value+='+'">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="/" onClick="calc.display.value+='/'">
          <input class="button end two" type="button" value="tan" onClick=”tan_function()”>
          <br>
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="E" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.718">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="pi" onClick="calc.display.value+=3.141">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="x^y" onClick="power_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="(" onClick="openpara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value=")" onClick="closepara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()">
          <br>
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN2" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.693">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN10" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.302">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log2E" onClick="calc.display.value+=1.442">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log10E" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.434">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="EXP" onClick="exp_function">

          </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color;
}


h1{
color: white;
}


    .container{
        background-image:   url(https://s26.postimg.org/frq6u3odl/texture-seamless-wood-3.jpg);
        position: relative;
        max-width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        border: 0;
}
.form.holder{
  max-width:500px;
  height:auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:2px groove #333;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 2px #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 #formone{
    padding-top:35px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}  

input, textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}



#display{ 
  height:60px;
  width:83%;
  color: blue;
  margin:3px;
  border:2px inset black;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:#c6c6c4;
}


.button.end.one,.button.number.one,.button.three,.button.opps.one,.button.number.two,.button.opps.two,.button.n, .button.sin,.button.end.two,.button.third.row {
font-size: 20px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
border: none;
color: white;
width:12.5%;
height:60px;
margin: 3px;
}


.button.end.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.number.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.three{
background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.button.opps.one{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  }


.button.number.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}


.button.opps.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.n{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.sin{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.button.end.two{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}


.button.third.row{
  background-color: #ef1a07;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 #heading{
  font-size: 20px !important;
 } 
}
```

Also, how do I get the **input-display** area to span the exact length of the buttons even when the screen size shrinks? Currently the display area is coded as having a width of **83%** but it doesn"t remain spanning the entire row of buttons as the screen shrinks in size. Why is that?

```
#display{ 
  height:60px;
  **width:83%;**
  color: blue;
  margin:3px;
  border:2px inset black;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:#c6c6c4;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of fixes to this - I have done it with floats instead here : https://codepen.io/BeerGrillz/pen/BwvrRG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all `br` tag except the first one. `br` tag has the white-space issue which is breaking your layout.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEyWBq

Comment: Thankyou all for the help! It is much appreciated! @KK, your solution worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Changing this part:

```
<input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()">
<br>
<input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
```

To this:

```
<input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()"><br><input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
```

Seems to fix it. Basically HTML is seeing a white space near the `<br>`, which causes everything after it to shift to the right. Changing your elements to `display:block;` and giving them `float:left;` will also cause white spaces to be ignored.